# iOS 9 UINavigation bar content is not centred after rotation in iOS 9?

Tags: layout, uinavigationbar, ios9

I noticed a bug in iOS 9, or may be I am not using something correctly.

In the following code in an empty project targeted for iPhone :

```
UIBarButtonItem *anotherButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Show" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(test:)];
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = anotherButton;

self.navBar.items = @[self.navigationItem];
```

I added a custom button to a navigation bar property. I noticed that after rotation from portrait to landscape, the button moves down and it is not centered correctly in the navigation bar.

[Portrait Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DVZkx.png) 
[Landscape Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iwiUN.png)
This code works fine if I compile for iOS 8.4 for example, but not on iOS 9.

Has anyone encountered this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to fix the problem with custom navigation bar class with and overridden method:

```
-(void) layoutSubviews
{
    [super layoutSubviews];

    for (UIView *view in self.subviews)
    {
        if ([view isKindOfClass:[UIView class]]      ||
            [view isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]]    ||
            [view isKindOfClass:[UISearchBar class]] ||
            [view isKindOfClass:[UILabel class]])
        {
        CGRect frame = view.frame;
        frame.origin.y = (self.frame.size.height - frame.size.height) / 2.f;
        view.frame = frame;
        }
    }
}
```

Other type of view classes can be added in the if statement. Its not the cleanest solution, but it will do for now.

Answer (score 1):

I've seen something similar on the iPad. When I start the app in portrait, then rotate to landscape, the View Controller its navigationItem.titleView doesn't align correctly anymore. I simply reset it after rotation as follows in Swift:

```
override func viewWillTransitionToSize(size: CGSize, withTransitionCoordinator coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
    coordinator.animateAlongsideTransition(nil) { (coordinator) -> Void in
        self.navigationItem.titleView = someView
    }
}
```

Swift 3:

```
override func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
    coordinator.animate(alongsideTransition: nil) {  (coordinator) -> Void in
        self.navigationItem.titleView = self.someView
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but my does exactly what You describe from the beginning :).